# Magento 2.3.0 + elasticsearch 6.4.2

Tags: magento2.3, elasticsearch

I'm trying to set up docker for magento 2.3.0 and elasticsearch 6.4.2

After containers are up i can connect to elasticsearch through browser and set up connection in magento 2 admin panel with message "Success".

Than i cleared cache and try to reindex catalogsearch_fulltext index. I recieved an error message:

```
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [{
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Enabling [_all] is disabled in 6.0. As a replacement, you can use [copy_to] on mapping fields to create your own catch all field."
        }],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Enabling [_all] is disabled in 6.0. As a replacement, you can use [copy_to] on mapping fields to create your own catch all field."
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

It's been throw out in

> vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php line 272

The same on elasticsearch 7.0.0

Does anyone has this problem? Can i somehow fixed it?

Comment: hey why do we need below "psr-4": { "Magento\\Elasticsearch\\": "" }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Magento 2.3.0 you have to use elasticsearch 5.x. [Refer to offical doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/project/project-conf-files_services-elastic.html).

**Composer of Magento 2.3.0**

```
{
    "name": "magento/module-elasticsearch",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.1.3||~7.2.0",
        "magento/module-advanced-search": "100.3.*",
        "magento/module-catalog": "103.0.*",
        "magento/module-catalog-search": "101.0.*",
        "magento/module-customer": "102.0.*",
        "magento/module-eav": "102.0.*",
        "magento/module-search": "101.0.*",
        "magento/module-store": "101.0.*",
        "magento/module-catalog-inventory": "100.3.*",
        "magento/framework": "102.0.*",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~2.0|~5.1"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "magento/module-config": "101.1.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Elasticsearch\\": ""
        }
    },
    "version": "100.3.0"
}
```

If you want to use elasticsearch 6.x you need to upgrade your magento to v2.3.1.

**Composer of Magento 2.3.1**

```
{
    "name": "magento/module-elasticsearch",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.1.3||~7.2.0",
        "magento/module-advanced-search": "100.3.*",
        "magento/module-catalog": "103.0.*",
        "magento/module-catalog-search": "101.0.*",
        "magento/module-customer": "102.0.*",
        "magento/module-eav": "102.0.*",
        "magento/module-search": "101.0.*",
        "magento/module-store": "101.0.*",
        "magento/module-catalog-inventory": "100.3.*",
        "magento/framework": "102.0.*",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~2.0|~5.1|~6.1"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "magento/module-config": "101.1.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Elasticsearch\\": ""
        }
    },
    "version": "100.3.1"
}
```